# Kivy images without kv language

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to make a small Programm, in order to learn how to add images without using the kv language, but it did not worked.
Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.image import Image

class Sprite(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = self.texture_size

class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Game, self).__init__()
        self.add_widget(Sprite(source='feind.png'))

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        Window.size = game.size
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

This is the error message I get:

```
   File "g.py", line 10, in __init__
     super(Sprite, self).__init__(**kwargs)
 TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Your question has nothing at all to do with Kivy or images. Please consider changing the title to something more relevant to what you are actually asking and adjusting your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong `Image` class.
You should use:

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
```

instead of

```
from kivy.core.image import Image
```

The constructor of the `kivy.core.image.Image` actually requires a positional argument. That is the cause of the TypeError. But you probably don't want to use that class here.
You most likely want to use an image widget, so you should use the `kivy.uix.image.Image` class. This one doesn't require a positional argument.